# Angular 2: Visual Code Studio Terminal Not Loading Automatically

Tags: visual-studio, angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

When you have changes  and you save it, terminal loads and says

`webpack: Compiled successfully.`

But lately in my VSC, it doesn't load automatically anymore. I still have to `Command C` and `ng serve` a project again and again to see changes on the localhost

> package.json

```
{
  "name": "gms",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "sw": "sw-precache --root=dist --config=sw-precache-config.js",
    "static-serve": "cd dist && live-server --port=4200 --host=localhost --entry-file=/index.html"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "sw-precache": "^5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: your `package.json` scripts?

Comment: @Aravind I already updated. Please check

Comment: `ng serve` will serve the files. but does not compile in watch mode. your exact trouble it is not compiling dynamically or the terminal not being opened

Comment: My terminal is open. What do you mean?

Comment: no elaborate exact issue your problem.